# JavaScript largest integer number corner cases

Tags: javascript, numbers, standards

Javascript is known to have 2<sup>53</sup> (9007199254740992, or 0x20000000000000) as the largest integer value for its `Number` object, as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t). I still don't understand why `Number(0x20000000000000)+1` produces `0x20000000000000`, but `Number(0x20000000000000)+2` produces `0x20000000000002` (9007199254740994). Can someone please explain?

Comment: Read this [Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Between 2^52=4,503,599,627,370,496 and 2^53=9,007,199,254,740,992 the representable numbers are exactly the integers. For the next range, from 2^53 to 2^54, everything is multiplied by 2, so the representable numbers are the even ones.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. I'd accept it as an answer if you post it.

Comment: You're welcome =) I posted the quote as Answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)

> Between 2^52=4,503,599,627,370,496 and 2^53=9,007,199,254,740,992 the representable numbers are exactly the integers. For the next range, from 2^53 to 2^54, everything is multiplied by 2, so the representable numbers are the even ones.